# Problem with my WebView in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, google-chrome, kotlin, webview

since a few days ago Google change Webview from Chrome to "Trichrome" My app is unresponsive in several Android Phones, Can I do something to use Chrome again a WebView? or there is any alternative to WebView?

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: Use **Android Browser** (previously known as chrome custom tabs). Here is a blog illustrates the implementation in kotlin. link:-
https://blog.mindorks.com/android-browser-lets-launch-chrome-custom-tabs-with-kotlin

Comment: I'm going to try that thanks!